# Is it possible to open a file using the command line in OSX and then open another one, but only after the first application has finished loading?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a set up for live shows using Ableton and Reason. I typically open the Ableton file, wait until it loads and then open Reason. The reason for this is because Reason acts as a slave to Ableton, so Ableton must finish loading before Reason starts.

I tried this (with single and double ampersands), but it wants to open both of them at the same time.

```
open "~/first_file.als" & open "~/second_file.rns"
```

If this can be done with AppleScript instead, I'd be willing to do that. I'm using Alfred to run the command.

Thanks!

Comment: The principal problem is that you can't tell when an application has finished loading a file. The open command is non-blocking and just fires away. The `-W` switch will make it block until the application is quit again. I can only think of manual sleep timers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try letting your command sleep for a few seconds (or however long it takes ableton to load)

i.e...

```
#!/bin/bash

open "~/first_file.als" 
sleep 10
open "~/second_file.rns"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use AppleScript — its open commands block the script until an application has finished opening a file.

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Live"
open POSIX file ((system attribute "HOME") & "/Audio/Template Project/Template.als")
end
tell app "Finder" -- open in the default application
open POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Beach.jpg" as alias
end'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with one line.

```
open "~/first_file.als" ; sleep 5 ;  open "~/second_file.rns"
```

NOTE: Adjust the sleep time as needed.

Unfortunately a sleep may indeed be necessary depending on what you are truly wanting to achieve.